# Как осуществить поиск по 2-м аргументам и более с помощью метода startsWith?

Tags: java

```
static private String printTextPerRole(String[] roles, String[] textLines) {
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder("");
    for (String role : roles) {
        output.append(role + ":\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < textLines.length; i++) {
            if (textLines[i].startsWith(role & ": ")) {
                output.append(i + 1 + ") ");
                output.append(textLines[i].substring(role.length() + 2));
                output.append("\n");                   
            }

        }
        output.append("\n");            
    }
    return output.toString();
}
```

Как можно изменить строку для поиска нужных символов if (textLines[i].startsWith(role)) Так как в строке role(в массиве лежат {Городничий,
Аммос Федорович}) обозначены строки без : , далее я добавляю к ним ":\n". Но так как имеются во втором параметре строки textLines - находяться те же самые слова, но уже с двойными :: или дефисом - то не получается индентифецировать нужный параметр. Как быть с этим? Т.е. как сделать поиск более универсальным? (Надеюсь я правильно выразил свою мысль)

Comment: а откуда вы берете эти два массива?

Comment: roles:
Городничий
Аммос Федорович
Артемий Филиппович
Лука Лукич
textLines:
Городничий: Я пригласил вас, господа, с тем, чтобы сообщить вам пренеприятное известие: к нам едет ревизор.
Аммос Федорович: Как ревизор?
Артемий Филиппович: Как ревизор?
Городничий: Ревизор из Петербурга, инкогнито. И еще с секретным предписаньем.
Аммос Федорович: Вот те на!
Артемий Филиппович: Вот не было заботы, так подай!
Лука Лукич: Господи боже! еще и с секретным предписаньем!

Comment: Это 2 исходных массива. Которые нужно сложить в 1 строку.

Comment: Городничий:
1) Я пригласил вас, господа, с тем, чтобы сообщить вам пренеприятное известие: к нам едет ревизор.
4) Ревизор из Петербурга, инкогнито. И еще с секретным предписаньем.

Аммос Федорович:
2) Как ревизор?
5) Вот те на!

Артемий Филиппович:
3) Как ревизор?
6) Вот не было заботы, так подай!

Лука Лукич:
7) Господи боже! еще и с секретным предписаньем!

Comment: откуда вы берете эти массивы?

Comment: В задании одного из онлайн курсов. https://stepik.org/course/Java-%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81-187/

Comment: у вас есть какие-либо ограничения? можно ли использовать Map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static String printTextPerRole(String[] roles, String[] textLines) {

    StringBuilder print = new StringBuilder();
    for (String role : roles) {
        String roleReplace = role.replace(":","");
        print.append(roleReplace + ":\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < textLines.length; i++) {
            if (textLines[i].startsWith(roleReplace + ":")) {
                print.append(i + 1 + ") ");
                print.append(textLines[i].substring(roleReplace.length() + 2) + "\n");
            }
        }
        print.append("\n");
    }
    return print.toString();
}
```

Comment: Я чуть допилил код и все получилось

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
private String printTextPerRole(String[] roles, String[] textLines) {
    //String resultString = "", temp1 = "";
    StringBuilder resultString = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();

    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < roles.length; i++) {
        resultString.append( roles[i]);
        resultString.append(":\n");

        for (int j = 0; j < textLines.length; j++) {
            if (textLines[j].equals("0"))
                continue;
            else {
                //читаю автора
                while (textLines[j].charAt(count) != ':') {
                    temp.append( textLines[j].charAt(count));
                    count++;
                }
                //если нужный автор
                if (roles[i].equals(temp.toString())) {
                    count = count + 2;
                    resultString.append(j + 1);
                    resultString.append(") ");
                    for (; count < textLines[j].length(); count++) {
                        resultString.append( textLines[j].charAt(count));
                    }
                    resultString.append("\n");
                    textLines[j] = "0";
                }
                temp.setLength(0);
                count = 0;
            }
        }
        resultString.append("\n");
    }
    return resultString.toString();
}
```

Comment: Я использовал другое решение.